# Can't connect to TFS server from Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3: "Failed to load workspaces: Host contacted, but no TFS service found"

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, azure-devops

I am having an issue where I am not able to connect to my TFS server from Intellij IDEA 2016.1.3. For the sake of this example, assume that the url to my TFS server is: **https://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com.** Since I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 urls, I am going to omit the "https" part from some of the urls in the description below, but rest assured that it is present in the actual url. Also assume that the name of my collection is **"mycol"**. Finally, note that I have enabled alternate authentication credentials for this server from TFS security.

Here are the repro steps from Intellij IDEA:

1. Go to: VCS->TFS->**Edit Configuration**
2. The "Manage TFS Servers and Workspaces" dialog opens, click "**Add...**"

The "Add Team Foundation Server" dialog opens, fill out the details:

**Address:** https://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com

Here, I have also tried "://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/mycol" and "://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" (with https in front)

**Auth:** Alternate

**User name:** my microsoft (live) id

**Password:** password for alternate credentials as specified in Visual Studio Team Services.

3. Click OK
4. I get the error message:

**"Failed to load workspaces: Host contacted, but no TFS service found"**

After this, the server is still added, ***but with the wrong url***. For some reason, Intellij IDEA appends **"myurlsegment"** to the original url, and I get the following for server name:

://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/**myurlsegment**

Instead of this:
://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/**mycol** (or ://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/**DefaultCollection**)

Of course since I don't have anything under the url:
://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/**myurlsegment**, I can't add any workspaces or do anything with this server added in such manner - it's useless.

Any ideas what may be causing this error?

**EDIT:**

Btw I am able to connect just fine to my TFS server from Visual Studio 2015. I noticed that the url in Visual Studio is indeed shown as: 
**myurlsegment**.visualstudio.com/**myurlsegment**, so this may not be the problem. I also looked the the IntelliJ IDEA log, and found this:

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "POST /myurlsegment/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; 
action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Registration/03/GetRegistrationEntries"[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "Authorization: Basic [\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: myurlsegment.visualstudio.com[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "Content-Length: 270[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - >> "[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,021 [ ]  DEBUG -        httpclient.wire.content - >> ""

2016-07-07 08:29:01,721 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"

2016-07-07 08:29:01,721 [ ]  DEBUG -         httpclient.wire.header - << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which plugin are you using to connect to VSTS from Intellij?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I am using the "TFS Integration" plugin - it comes enabled by default when you install IntelliJ IDEA. Its version, as displayed in "plugin settings", is: 999.999

Comment: I just try to download this plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=idea and install it with Intellij2016.1.3 but get incompatible error. Can you try with this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=idea? It works on my side.

Comment: I tried the plugin you specified, and I am able to connect to my TFS server with it! But I need to check how well this plugin will support the rest of my workflow. For now, it may be a viable workaround. Btw you should not have to install the "TFS Integration" plugin, it comes pre-installed with IDEA and enabled by default: (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-tfs-integration.html).  I also edited my original post to add some more info on the error I am getting from the IDEA log. Thanks for your help with this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The plugin does not listed in my IDEA, that's why I try to download and install it.

Comment: This is strange, because the plugin is bundled with Intellij and you should not need to install it separately. Just to confirm: if you go to the VCS menu, you don't see the TFS option? Did you try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-tfs-integration.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm using community version. I will check with Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get the same behavior as you with Ultimate edition. Try the walk around here: [IDEA-155939 "Failed to load workspaces: Host contacted, but no TFS service found" while adding "*.visualstudio.com" TFS server](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155939). It works at my side.

> - Close IDEA
> - Locate tfs servers cache file:
>
>   - Windows - `%USER_HOME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\<VERSION>\Cache\VersionControl.config`. `<VERSION>` could be one of 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 values.
>   - Other - `<IDEA_OPTIONS_FOLDER>/tfs-servers.xml`
> - Correct `uri` attribute of corresponding `ServerInfo` tag from `https://<TEAM>.visualstudio.com/<TEAM>` value to just `https://<TEAM>.visualstudio.com/`
> - Start IDEA

Comment: Thank you!! This solved the problem. The url in my VersionControl.config was: https://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/myurlsegment, and I changed it to: https://myurlsegment.visualstudio.com/. Now I am able to add the server normally, and see all projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the correct URL path for the server to use was found in

`C:\Users\[yourUserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Configuration\VersionControl\LocalItemExclusions.config` at the top of the file, in the line starting with

`<TeamProjectCollection id=`